# How often does ubuntu update their python versions after CVEs?

Tags: apt, python

Python3 versions prior to February 16. 2021 has a [vulnerability (CVE 2021-3177)](https://python-security.readthedocs.io/vuln/ctypes-buffer-overflow-pycarg_repr.html).
I see that the current version of python3.7 on ubuntu 18.04 is 3.7.5. The CVE is fixed in python 3.7.10.

How is this usually handled? Will ubuntu usually create a new package with python 3.7.10 that has the fix, or do users normally compile from source or use pyenv if they want the latest version?

Comment: Fixes are usually back-ported for *stable* releases, unless it's more work to back-port the fix than upgrading the package to the later version (as recently occurred with a `thunderbird` package for a stable release; warnings went out about this).  You can use https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/ to look up fixes for various CVEs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as you installed a package through one of Canonical's official channels and are running a supported release of Ubuntu (or are part of the Extended Support program), they take care of updates. You will not need to do anything beyond `sudo apt upgrade`. That said, some updates may take longer than others depending on the severity of the issue.

You can find [specific information about CVE-2021-3177 on the security website](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-3177), including which versions have the bug and the status of the update.